# Как преобразовать String в Boolean?

Tags: java, android

Делаю так:

```
Boolean bbb;
bbb =  Boolean.valueOf("1");
Log.d("MyLog","bbb: "+Boolean.parseBoolean(String.valueOf(bbb)));
bbb = Boolean.valueOf("0");
Log.d("MyLog","bbb: "+Boolean.parseBoolean(String.valueOf(bbb)));
```

Каждый раз получается `bbb: false`.

Я знаю, что надо текстом писать `"true"` или `"false"`, но мне нужно `"1"` или `"0"`.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String s = "1";
Boolean b = s.equals("1");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "true";
```

В Boolean (объект):

```
Boolean b1 = Boolean.valueOf(s);
```

В boolean (примитивный):

```
boolean b2 = Boolean.parseBoolean(s);
```